# Why does Service crash when I rerun program?

Tags: java, android, service

I'm now starting to write a service routine and I get an error message everytime I rerun my code without altering anything.

Here's the Service routine:

public class PollingService extends Service{

```
private static final String TAG = PollingService.class.getSimpleName();

private Polling updater;

public boolean isRunning = false;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    updater = new Polling();
    Log.d(TAG, "On Create'd");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Start the Polling updater
    if(!this.isRunning){
        updater.start();
        this.isRunning = true;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "On Start'd");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public synchronized void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Stop the Polling updater
    if(this.isRunning){
        updater.interrupt();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "On Destroy'd");
}

// Polling Thread
class Polling extends Thread {
    static final long DELAY = 3000;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            try {
                // Do something
                Log.d(TAG, "Polling run'ing");
                // Sleep
                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Interrupted
                isRunning = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

When I run the app I see in the LogCat "On Create'd" and "On Start'd", and "Polling run'ing", however, I rerun the program to see if I get "On Start'd" only in the LogCat. But instead I get this error:

ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.project.keegan/.StartApp }
ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

And when I check the LogCat it still says, "Polling run'ing". So I went in the emulator: Menu -> App Manager -> and I stopped the Service.

When I rerun the program I got the same two errors and my app started but not the service. But here's the funny part, whenever I do any alteration to my code (like if I just pressed the spacebar and then backspace) and clicked Save, and then rerun the program, the Service runs again.

Here's the Class I call it from:

public class StartApp extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

```
TextView disp_hello;
Button but_go2send, but_go2request;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_app);
    Vars();
    startService(new Intent(this, PollingService.class));
    but_go2send.setOnClickListener(this);
    but_go2request.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

.
.
.
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with your code. Eclipse is just smart enough to detect that you did not change any code and it skips replacing the app on the device.

And instead of restarting the app (which would involve killing it) it just brings it back to front.

If you want to restart it, you need to exist / kill the app or do like you did and insert a space.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I get what you're saying. I'm going to test this out on my cellphone now: I'm going to start the app, stop the service and restart the app and the service should restart.

Comment: Yep works fine thank you...I guess that's what you'd call a false alarm.

Comment: @KeeganForde It can be confusing sometimes, but it is no crash. Also Services don't stop when you leave the Activity that started it. (`return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);` tells Android to keep the Service running -> [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) until you explicitly stop it via `stopService`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not sure where in the app I want the Service to stop running, but when I reach there I'll use that. @zapl

Comment: @KeeganForde Symmetry is usually good: if you start it in `onCreate` stop it in `onDestroy`. Or use `onStart` / `onStop` instead. You can even switch between Activities using that pattern since `onStop` of the Activity you leave is called after `onStart` of the Activity you go to. Also services are not actually stopped if the new Activity requests to start the Service before the old Activity requests to stop it.